# Checking for overlaps in two long lists of items in Python

Tags: python

I have two lists (list1 and list2) that contain 10 million names of companies. Each list has no duplicates, but some companies appear in both lists. And I want to find what those companies are. I wrote the code below:

```
list_matched = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(len(list2)):
        if list1[i] == list2[j]:
            list_matched.append(list1[i])
```

The problem of this code is that it never finishes executing. My question is what I can do to finish this task within a reasonable amount of time. The size of 10 million names seems to be too big to handle.

Comment: Are these lists by chance sorted to begin with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use set logic. It is specifically designed for this task.

```
a = set(list1)
b = set(list2)

companies_in_both = a & b
```

(This will produce a `set` as the output. If you need it as a list, just pass the set to `list()`.)

Comment: Note that if you can create them as sets in the first place instead of converting lists to sets, it should be faster.

Comment: @porglezomp how do you create such a thing as a set to begin with? Presumably this data comes from either an api, a database, or a flat file…

Comment: If it's from a flat file, you `.add` to the set instead of `.append`ing to a list while you're building it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend making a set from one list and checking the other, e.g:

```
inlist1 = set(list1)
list_matched = [x for x in list2 if x in inlist1]
```

Of course you can do it the other way 'round, depending which list's order (if any) you want to preserve -- this snippet preserves the order of `list2`.